# ModelChoiceFilter gives "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." when submitted

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-filter

I am using django-filters to filter my **products** based on **brand**. When i submit my form, i get "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." I used *ModelChoiceFilter* because the docs said that is it suitable for ForeignKey relationships.

Form successfully rendered as checkboxes as intended on product.html:

[form successfully rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvslR.png)

When form is submitted with checkboxes selected, error arises:

[ModelChoiceFilter gives error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFScs.png)

Surprisingly when i changed the filter to *ModelMultipleChoiceFilter*, I did not get a "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." error. I wonder why *ModelChoiceFilter* would throw this error.

here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Brand(models.Model):

    bool_choices = (
        (True, 'Yes'),
        (False, 'No'),
    )
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class Product(MPTTModel):

    parent = TreeForeignKey('self',  blank = True, null = True, related_name = 'children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="brand") #one to many relationship between Brand and Product class
    category = TreeManyToManyField(Category, blank = True)
```

**filters.py**

```
import django_filters
from product.models import Product, Category, Brand
from django.db import models
from django import forms

       
class BrandFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    brand = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset= Brand.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, empty_label = None, to_field_name = 'name')

    class Meta:
        model = Product 
        fields = ('brand',)
```

**views.py**

```
def product(request):

    products = Product.objects.all()
    brandFilter = BrandFilter(request.GET, queryset= products )

    products = brandFilter.qs
    

    context = {'products':products,'brandFilter': brandFilter}
    return render(request, 'home/product.html', context)
```

**product.html**

```
...
<div>
    <form method = "get">
        {{ brandFilter.form.as_p }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Search </button>
    </form>
</div>

<div>
    {% for product in products %}
        <div>
            {{ product }}

        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I have tried submitting the form with 1 checkbox activated and the error persists:
[Error still arises with 1 checkbox activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti2Hv.png)

Answer (score 0):

`ModelChoiceFilter` only allows a single selection because it uses the [django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/2.0.0/django_filters/filters.py#L345) for [validating selected values](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.8/django/forms/models.py#L1253).

However, you have it instantiated with a `forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget.
This means that the selected value passed as a list and [this line](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.8/django/forms/models.py#L1253) executes as

```
value = self.queryset.get(**{name: [<selected_value>,...]})
```

and raises a `self.queryset.model.DoesNotExist` exception.

If you want many brands to be selected for a product (i.e. one product having many brands), the filter to use is the [`ModelMultipleChoiceFilter`](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/2.0.0/django_filters/filters.py#L352) which uses `ModelMultipleChoiceField` and [validates against a list of values](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.8/django/forms/models.py#L1294).

Otherwise to maintain a one-to-one relationship between product and brand and reflect that in your form, use a form widget which selects a single value such as [RadioSelect](http://CheckboxInput), [Select](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.8/django/forms/widgets.py#L669)

Comment: Hey thanks for the your help! I sorta get it now?

0

"ModelChoiceFilter only allows a single selection because it uses the django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField for validating selected values." 

I submitted the form with 1 checkbox only activated and i still got the error (see added image above). 



actually, the brand has a one to many relationship with product, in which one brand can have many products.  my goal with this filter is to do something like a "AND" operation where if i have 2 brands checkbox selected, my program should return any product associated with those brands.